# When old field revisions should be deleted from the database?

Tags: 8, database, paragraphs

I have a question about old fields revisions in Drupal 8. For example I have "Full Title" field in different paragraphs. I have deleted this field from one of the paragraphs, for example from the "Test Paragraph". In the database there are tables: **paragraph__field_section_full_title** and **paragraph_revision__field_section_full_title**. In these tables all of the records for test_paragraph bundle deleted column values changed from 0 to 1.

After the *field_cron()* that should delete these records all of the records from paragraph__field_section_full_title was deleted as it expected.

But in the **paragraph_revision__field_section_full_title** table old revisions for test_paragraph bundle whith deleted column = 1 is not deleted. When they should be deleted? Is it automatic process or not? Where I need to look to check if abything broken?

Thanks.

Here screenshot below of the table of not deleted old revisions:

[image]